# Need to create the directory on EFS with kubernetes pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

what will be the definition file, if I need to mount my efs with pod and then create a directory with the correct permission?

efs id lets say:- fs-c98c345

Need to run the below command after efs mount on pod.

```
mkdir <efs mount path>/prometheus
chown -R 1000:2000 <efs mount path>/prometheus
```

Answer (score 0):

To manage and use efs from kubernetes(on AWS) you should use efs-provisioner. You can install and configure efs-provisioner through helm chart available here https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/efs-provisioner.

Comment: I don't want to use eks-provisioner, I am using csi driver at present

Comment: Well, I haven't used csi myself but I can see helm chart available for csi configuration here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/tree/master/helm, you can try it out.